# what unit of measurement does quaternion ::getangle() returns the angle in?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am trying to write a UI to reflect the current orientation of the robot using the tf information published.  While printing the angle value using the getangle() function provided by tf::quaternion i noticed that the value is not in degree. I also noticed from the API that the angle() function returns half angles.

Do anyone knows what unit of measurmen does the getangle() function returns the angle value in?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174495/what-unit-of-measurement-does--quaternion-::getangle()-returns-the-angle-in?/) by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Angle units should be radians unless otherwise specified. Defaults are in [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1